# why getUserPlaylists() function is not working?

Tags: reactjs, spotify

Hey I was making a spotify clone using react and spotify-web-api-js library so when i am calling getUserPlaylists functin it gives a null object

```
spotify.getUserPlaylists().then((playlists) => {
console.log(playlists)
}).catch((err)=>console.log(err));
```

and the response i am getting is this

```
playlists:
href: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/py1j6feeij18g2e0wr8crdjd4/playlists?offset=0&limit=20"
items: []
limit: 20
next: null
offset: 0
previous: null
total: 0
__proto__: Object
```

i have checked there are playlists associated with the account.
here is the github for  the project: https://github.com/satyaarthchhabra/spotify-clone-boom

the link for the spotify library i am using is https://www.npmjs.com/package/spotify-web-api-js

Comment: Does the user have any songs in their playlist?

Comment: yes the user have songs

Comment: Can you see what happens when you pass the `userId` to [`getUserPlaylists`](https://doxdox.org/jmperez/spotify-web-api-js#src-spotify-web-api.js-constr.prototype.getuserplaylists)? That way we can determine if the issue could be coming from the current logged in user or from the API.